# Can we use 2 different url on same anchor tag for javascript disabled and enabled condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Can we use 2 different url on same  for javascript disabled and enabled condition

If javascript is enabled then link should be `<a href="link1">`

and If javascript is disabled then link should be `<a href="link2">`

Comment: -1 for question in title. Why do you have to do this EVERYTIME?

Comment: As for the question: Yes.

But that probably wasn't the answer you where looking for. ;-)

Comment: I do not believe in numbering.

Comment: I got answer for the question. so it doesn't matter to me if i get any downvote

Comment: +1 to bring this back up.  Not sure why it is being down-voted...

Comment: @Jitendra I assure you that numbering exists, are you a numbering agnostic?

Comment: Jitendra, if you got your answer, you should accept it.  It will help people in the future!

Comment: @Buggabill It's not the best written question out there, but it's understandable. 2 downvotes does seem a bit excessive.

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. You should have one link, which goes to a page that works with or without JS: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: @David: Progressive enhancement should of course always be the aim. however it's not always feasable to retrofit an existing site so that it works properly without JS. It's not ideal but that's the reality sometimes.

Comment: +1 Interesting question and answers, plus there is no Rule that says a Title cannot also be a question - you could make a case that all Titles should explicitly be questions (not that I'd agree, but you could argue it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the JS disabled URL in the markup, then on page load use JS to replace the url with the enabled URL.

```
HTML:
<a id="id" href="js_disabled_url" />Link</a>


jQuery example:
$(function() {
    $('#id').attr('href','js_enabled_url');
});
```

This should degrade gracefully.

Comment: You're welcome, The question was tagged with jQuery so I made the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just write a JavaScript which finds the element you want to change the `href` of when the page has loaded.

Example using JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.changeable').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://google.com/lol');
    });
});
```

(Untested, but you get the idea.)

So basically, if the user has disabled JavaScript, the default link is used, otherwise the new URL given by the script is used. So your HTML should contain the link that should be used when JavaScript is *disabled*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can have one url on the html page, and if javascript is working, have the javascript change the url on the anchor.

That way you can ensure that the second url only works if javascript is enabled.

The problem is that if javascript was enabled when the page was loaded, and later disabled then you won't know.

But, if you just have an onclick on the anchor, then you can change the url when it is clicked on, then it will always work correctly, as, if they disable javascript after the page is loaded it will still go to the non-javascript url, and if the onclick works then it will go to the other url.